# WinUI 3 ClickOnce - Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll'

Tags: c#, clickonce, winui-3

I'm trying to publish a WinUI 3 app with Visual Studio, .net Core version 6.0.22.   The publish profile is set to publish to a local folder, ClickOnce. Install location is "CD, DVD, or USB," all the application files are set to "Include," I've tried both the Self-Contained and Framework-Dependent deployment modes.

It's using the single-project Visual Studio template, so there's not a separate project for Packaging.

It installs and runs fine on my development machine. When I try it on any other computer the install completes without any problems, but when I try to run it, it just crashes. I check Event Viewer and see the error, "Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.

There is no Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll anywhere in the project folder, so I assume this is a dependency or framework that needs to be pre-installed on the computer. How do I figure out what this dependency is? And how do I get ClickOnce to include it in the "Self-Contained" deployment mode or add it as a dependency that installs as part of the setup process?

Comment: I suggest you could try to package the app as an [MSIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps) instead of deploying it using ClickOnce.

Comment: This might be related to this ongoing [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/2443).

Comment: Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll is deployed with the WinAppSDK Runtime. What you can try is 1) install it manually https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/downloads or 2) add   `<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>` to your project (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/package-and-deploy/self-contained-deploy/deploy-self-contained-apps). But Not sure the later supports clickonce scenarios. There are lots of "self-contained" confusions in that area between the .NET as a "framework" vs WinAppSDK as a "framework", w/o even speaking of "packaging"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Adding <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained> resulted in the error "Downloading file:///D:/Application Files/AppName_1_0_0_5/dcompi.dll.deploy did not succeed" during the install on the other machine.  I tried the suggestion in the github issue to delete the bin and obj folders, restore the NuGet packages, and Rebuild. No luck. I decided to just give up on ClickOnce and use MSIX instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/single-project-msix?tabs=csharp